# Application Won't 'new' when called

Tags: wpf, xaml, new-operator

I am calling a new xaml application with some parameter inputs using the word new, but it does not seem to be working.  I am also attempting to use onclosing to set it to null.  When launching it for the first time it works (everything is new), but launching it after it finished, it seems to continue its previous state (brings to finished score board).  Here is the snipplet of the code . . .

```
        quizUI = new QuizzUI.MainWindow(App.User, true);
        quizUI.Closed += (o, s) =>
            {
                quizUI = null;
            };
        quizUI.LaunchQuiz(qSet);
```

this is hooked to a button event. does anyone know how i can absolutely new this object's state every time?  the two paramters are user's info and second one is to shortcut without prompt screen/loading screen.

Here is the code for QuizzUI.MainWindow.LaunchQuizz:

```
    public void LaunchQuiz(GameQuizzSet quiz)
    {
        this.Hide();
        quizz = new QuizzContainer()
        {
            QSet = quiz,
        };

        if (isShortCutted)
        {
            bool? diag = quizz.ShowDialog();

            if (diag.HasValue)
            {
                quizz.Close();
                Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            quizz.ShowDialog();
            this.Show();
        }
    }
```

the QuizzUI.MainWindow allows the user to select their profile and which quiz to execute.

Comment: You may want to post the contents of the LaunchQuiz method, since typically you would use window.Show();

Comment: ok that function has now been posted . . .